# npm run "npm run " enoent error

Tags: node.js, npm

Basically copying and pasting from a very popular fullstack redux tutorial. I cannot figure out why the second npm run is looking for that script in the node_modules folder, as oppose to just the package.json file

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js  --recursive",
  "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
},
```

npm run test -- --watch

```
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/home/l2silver/react-redux-rest/node_modules/test/package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-47-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "test" "--" "--watch"
npm ERR! cwd /home/l2silver/react-redux-rest
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /home/l2silver/react-redux-rest/node_modules/test/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/l2silver/react-redux-rest/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
npm ERR! weird error 34
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Does this also occur if you [update `npm`](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-nix-osx-linux-etc)? It was `npm@2` which introduced passing custom arguments to scripts (which you are doing) but you are using `npm@1.3` (which is over 2 years old and no longer supported).

Comment: I'm afraid not. To be honest, I'm not sure what the problem was, but when I recloned the same project into a new folder, the error went away. So I'm chalking it up to improper dependency install

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and had the same version of node as you have (v0.10.25).
The solution for me was to update node to the newest version (v4.4.3).

Updated node with the installer from [the node website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and the `npm run test -- --watch` worked fine.